# Jquery appending span

Tags: jquery, html, dynamicform

How can I append `span` when creating form dynamically using jquery?

```js
for (var i in formField["Data"]) {
  console.log("Dummy $$$$$ " + formField["Data"][i]["field_id"]);
  $("div#form1").append(
    $("<input/>", {
      type: "text",
      id: formField["Data"][i]["field_id"],
      name: formField["Data"][i]["field_id"],
      placeholder: formField["Data"][i]["field_label"]
    }),
    $("<br/>")
  );
}
```

Comment: ...Where do you want the span ?

Comment: There's no span in the code.

Comment: I want span above all of the input fields.

Comment: $('#inputTitle').text(formField['Data'][i]['field_label']),     
I supplied that code inside my for loop but it's getting overridden by the last input value.

Comment: Sure, because ids are expected to be unique, and `text()` replaces the value.  It does not append a value.

Comment: Any suggest or example that may help in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I got the solution

```
for (var i in formField["Data"]) {
  console.log("Dummy $$$$$ " + formField["Data"][i]["field_id"]);
  $("div#form1").append(
  $("<span/>").text(formField['Data'][i]['field_label']),
    $("<input/>", {
      type: "text",
      id: formField["Data"][i]["field_id"],
      name: formField["Data"][i]["field_id"],
      placeholder: formField["Data"][i]["field_label"]
    }),
    $("<br/>")
  );
}
```